# Unable to see template

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to set a variable to template with `if` in the HTML. The issue is that I can't see my template and don't have any errors from the logs. I can see that elements are in the HTML but still can't see it.

The template is:

```
   <div class="list-group">                                                                             
       <div id="table_template">                                                                        
         <div id ="table"></div>                                                                        
               <script type="text/template" id="nextPage">                                              
               <% if (nextLink != "") { %>                                                       
               <nav><ul class="pager"><li><a href="#" id="next_page" >Next</a></li> </ul> </nav>        
               <%}%>                                                                           
                 </script>                                                                              
           </div>                                                                                       
       </div>                                                                                           
   </div>
```

and the view:

```
  var template = _.template($('#nextPage').html());
    view.$el.find('#nextPage').html(template(listSongs));
```

Update: Looks like I am unable to see it if I have script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script tag is used so that the browser does NOT render that piece into the whole DOM. You did that assuming that the script tag will print into the view but it won't.  You will need to inject it into the view. Try this:

```
<div class="list-group">                                                                             
   <div id="table_template">                                                                        
     <div id ="table"></div><div id="nextPage"></div>
           <script type="text/template" id="nextPageTemplate">                                              
           <% if (nextLink != "") { %>                                                       
           <nav><ul class="pager"><li><a href="#" id="next_page" >Next</a></li> </ul> </nav>        
           <%}%>                                                                           
             </script>                                                                              
       </div>                                                                                       
   </div>
```

Then in your view it can look like this:

```
var template = _.template($('#nextPageTemplate').html());
view.$el.find('#nextPage').html(template(listSongs));
```

Now I'm unsure if your view El is "list-group" (but I hope it is).